# Battery Management System (BMS)

Tags: lithium-ion, discharge, batteries

Suppose that a lithium-ion cell having total charge capacity Q=10Ah is discharged at a rate of 1A for 30min. What is the net change in the cell's state of charge (in percent)? Round to the nearest percent.

Comment: Reads too much ltke a homework question to deserve an answer. What have you done so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: on coursera queston is there.but now i got answer. i was little confuse with signs while solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Delta Q = I \Delta T$$ right?  You're given

$$
I = 1A \\
\Delta T = 0.5 h \\
\Delta Q = I \Delta T = 0.5 Ah \\
Q_0 = 10 Ah
$$

Thus $$Q_0 - \Delta Q = 9.5 Ah$$  You subtract because of implications of the word "discharge".  Alternatively you could say that the current `I` is negative.

Comment: yup its -10% . i got it later

Comment: it should be -5% .............................

Answer (score 0):

Z(t) = -1/Q·integral 0-t (eta·i·time)dt
Q=10 Ah
time = 30 min = 0.5h
i = 1 A
eta = 1
Z(t) = -1/10·(1·1·0.5) = -0.05
SOC % = -0.05·100 = -5%
or
Total charge discharged = Discharge rate · Discharge time = 1A · 0.5 hours = 0.5Ah

Change in SoC = (Charge discharged / Total capacity) · 100%
Change in SoC = (0.5Ah / 10Ah) · 100% = 5%
Since discharge decreases the SoC, the net change is negative:
Net change in SoC = -5%